# How to mock LocalCache in unit testing with Mockito

Tags: java, spring, mockito

My base class uses java library responsible for auditing. This Library uses Builder pattern to retrieve objects from my Java Project for Auditing Operations (*Inserts into Multiple tables by creating keys on it's own.*)
This Library uses `com.google.common.cache` to manage cache values. i.e. String and Value. 
`LoadingCache<String, Long>`

**sample Example of how my project uses library**

```java
auditOperation = LibraryAuditBuilder.builder()
//some param
.build()
LibraryAuditingService.process(auditOperation);
```

My base application and Library runs on Oracle Database and my unit tests uses HSQL database. Given all necessary scripts in `@Before` I would want to unit test execution of my code.

`@Before` method

```java
@Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
//create db scrips and other declarations
}
```

**I have tried 2 approach so far**

1) Created `LoadingCache` and put sample values in it so that UnitTest can use it later in execution.

```java
longLoadingCache.put("4028eeb0-1d2d-daba-011d-2e36e4b2110e",(long)203);
longLoadingCache.put("4028ee14-24b4-5221-0124-b47bbb1d1232",(long)102);
```

2) `@Mock` object of `LoadingCache` and values in it to be used later in Tests

```java
when(longLoadingCache.get("4028eeb0-1d2d-daba-011d-2e36e4b2110e")).thenReturn((long)203);     
when(longLoadingCache.get("4028ee14-24b4-5221-0124-b47bbb1d1232")).thenReturn((long)102);
```

Current output with both of above approach

```java
- com.google.common.cache.CacheLoader$InvalidCacheLoadException: CacheLoader returned null for key 4028ee14-24b4-5221-0124-b47bbb1d1232.
```

So my question is, **How Can I Pass/Mock values of Cache so that UnitTests don't have to look for values in Library class.**

Comment: is this spring application? have you aware of `@MockBean`?

Comment: Yes, my application uses spring beans with OSGI packaging. And no I am not aware of `@MockBean`, I will google it.

Comment: show your test class code, that will be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although answer from @Lukasz was perfectly valid but required much more effort. After spending some hours I was able to create simpler solution for this problem. 
Rather then `@Mock`ing `LocalCache`, I can just `@Mock` class(Library class) providing cache values, as they were static values we don't care how library itself retrieves it.
something like following

```java
 busAuditOperationDao = mock(BusAuditOperationDao.class);
 busAuditProcessDao = mock(BusAuditProcessDao.class);
```

in `@Before` method I can specify whatever values I want, which will be used in `@test` classes

```java
when(busAuditOperationDao.getAuditOperationIdFromGuid("4028eeb0-1d2d-daba-011d-2e36e4b2110e")).thenReturn((long) 102);
when(busAuditProcessDao.getAuditProcessIdFromGuid("4028ee14-24b4-5221-0124-b47bbb1d1232")).thenReturn((long)203);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider creating your own facade bean wrapping the 3rd-party library (e.g. AuditProcessor). When the facade is injected using @Autowire or @Inject you can easily mock it in the test code and check if your wrapping facade (read: the library) has been properly used. If you don't trust the library you could unit test the wrapping facade and all corner cases in isolated environment without HSQL. If you want even more control you could introduce an interface (e.g. IAuditProcessor) and create a dummy implementation which will be @Autowired in test using Spring profiles.

To summarize:

- HSQL-based test should test if the facade is called when expected and with correct arguments
- corner cases / caching should be tested separately in isolated test cases without HSQL / Spring context

Comment: Thanks @Lukasz, your answer is perfectly valid. However I have found another solution where I can just `@Mock` library class and set mocked values